# Using Thumbnails on Blogger Lightbox

Tags: thumbnails, lightbox, blogger

I want to show my photos with same size on posts. The problem is that I have horizontal and vertical photos ( for example 1500x600px and 600x1500px) and when i create a gallery there is a irregular pattern because of  the sizes.
So, I thought using same sized thumbnails (for example square) for every photos was the solution. To some level, it worked. I mean, I created a fine pattern with using thumbnail pictures.

The problem is that source of the images and source of the thumbnails. Lightbox does not allow this kind of usage. For example:

```
<a href="**Original Photo Link**" imageanchor="1" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" height="226" src="**Thumbnail Picture Link**" width="320" /></a>
```

When ı create this kind of arrangement, I can show my gallery on post, but when i click the image, ıt is opening like a normal image url, not in gallery view.

Is there any solution for this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using lightGallery is a solution that has a few issues on user interface.

[Link](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/)